# IDA Dalvik debugger on Device JDWP error: INVALID_OBJECT

Tags: debugging, apk, ida

[image]

I get this error message when trying to run on my android device.  Played around with the settings and no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I just load one **class.dex** because my IDA version dosen't support multidex.You have to upgrade your IDA to at least 7.1 which can load a apk file which includes all the **.dex** files.

You can check the [jdwp reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdwp/jdwp-protocol.html) and [IDA release](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/7.1/index.shtml) for more details.